# trying to convert if else to switch case

Tags: jquery

I have the following code where i am trying to convert the following code in switch/case but i am really a starter as to how to do it

```js
if (data.statusmsg == '') { 
  type = 'warning'
} else { 
  type = 'success'
}

if (data.noaction != '') {
  text = data.noaction
} else {
  text = data.statusmsg
}

if (data.statusmsg != '' && data.noaction == '') {
  text = data.statusmsg 
}

if (data.statusmsg != '' && data.noaction != '') {
  type = 'info',text = data.statusmsg + "<hr>" + data.noaction
}

if (data.statusmsg == '' && data.noaction == '') { 
  type = 'success', text = data.statusmsg
}
```

Please guide

Thanks

Comment: A switch statement is useful for if you have a single variable that can be many different values.  In this case, you have two variables.  For this to be a switch you would have to contrive a way to turn the two variable values into distinct single values for the switch statement to operate upon.  IMHO, it would be better to leave this as the if statements.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm reading your logic correctly, it can be condensed down to one conditional, with two sub conditionals.  This would make more sense that trying to coax it into a switch statement.

```js
if (data.statusmsg == '') {
  if ( data.noaction == '' ) {
    type = 'success';
    text = data.statusmsg;
  } else {
    type = 'warning';
    text = data.noaction;
  }
} else {
  if ( data.noaction == '' ) {
    type = 'success';
    text = data.statusmsg;
  } else {
    type = 'info';
    text = data.statusmsg + "<hr>" + data.noaction;
  }
};
```